# Altura de un elemento en el documento

Tags: javascript, html5

¿Con qué método puedo saber la distancia que hay entre el comienzo del documento .html cuando se lo visualiza en el navegador y un elemento que forma parte del contenido del .html?

Esto es lo que he intentado hasta el momento:

```
var altura = $('#lbl_btn-menu').outerHeight(true);
console.log(altura);
```

y me encuentro buscando más información en w3schools mediante el `window.on()`

Answer (score 2):

si no recuerdo mal hay una función en jQuery se llama "offset" y te devuelve la posición de un elemento con respecto al documento. Suena como lo que estás buscando.

Sería algo como esto:

```
var distancia = $('#lbl_btn-menu').offset().top;
```

Esta es la [referencia](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: gracias por tu aporte, ya le veo que puedo hacer con ese método

Comment: Gracias @Sago78, no me fijé que olvidé pegar la referencia :)